# Ionic & ngCorgova Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm currently working on an Ionic / ngCordova Geolocation project were we want to be able to get the users current location.

I've managed to get the users location but unable to get the timeout refresh to continue seeing their location whilst moving.

Any advice/help would be highly appreciated.

```
   (function(angular, undefined) {
      "use strict";
      var app = angular.module('starter');

      app.controller('geoCtrl', function($cordovaGeolocation, $scope) {
        var self = this;

        var posOptions = {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 8000};
        $cordovaGeolocation
          .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
          .then(function (position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            self.location = lat +' - '+ long;
            console.log(self.location);
          }, function(err) {
            console.log('error:', error);
          });

        var watchOptions = {
          timeout : 1000,
          enableHighAccuracy: false
        };
        var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

        watch.then(
          null,
          function(err) {
          },
          function(position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            self.location = lat +' - '+ long;
            console.log(self.location);
        });

        watch.clearWatch();

      });
    })(angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `watch.clearWatch()` and what that does is, basically, reset the watcher.

According to the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#navigatorgeolocationclearwatch)

> **navigator.geolocation.clearWatch**
>
> Stop watching for changes to the device's location referenced by the
>   watchID parameter.
>
> `navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);`

Just comment that line and everything should work fine.